# Using web services over a proxy server Internet connection

Tags: c#, web-services, winforms

I have a Windows form application that's consuming web services over https and is working perfectly. Do I have to make any arrangement in my code for the case when the user has an Internet connection through a proxy server?

Comment: when u say "consuming web services over https", aren't the services accessed from remote machines? if it worked for this case, then I don't think you need to make any changes to your present code

Comment: I have the idea that the connection with the service was made assuming the Windows Internet settings, but there are applications like Firefox that have their own Internet settings, and this is the reason of my doubt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're ok. Here's an easy way to tell:  Run Fiddler2 and it'll insert itself as a proxy. While it's running, you'll see the proxy setting in Internet Explorer is set to localhost:8888 or something like that.   Try your app, and see if the traffic goes through fiddler. If so, then I think you'll be ok.  Note that java-stack apps like SoapUI, will NOT automatically be routed through fiddler, as that would need its own proxy. i.e. it won't follow the IE proxy settings.

http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler2/version.asp

Comment: YW.  And when you fire up Fiddler, try browsing some web pages in IE and then in FireFox. You'll see that FireFox doesn't get captured, as it has its own proxy settings. I think that tells me that it's using its own stack, and not WinInet.  Your app (and IE) should both be using WinInet.